# Cancelling execution of a method called with await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to cancel the execution of the DoSomethingAsync method which I call  using *await*.

When I click on the cancel button the execution is not cancelled and I don't see the "Execution was cancelled" message box, but instead I see the other message box.

I don't understand why it's not working. I am still learning this part of C# and I took this example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127291/C-vNext-New-Asynchronous-Pattern#heading0015 (I simplified it).

```
public class MyClass : Class 
{

  CancellationTokenSource cts;

  private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    await DoSomethingAsync();
  }


  private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    cts.Cancel();
  }


  async void DoSomethingAsync()
  {
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        await SuperSlowProcess();
        MessageBox.Show("You will only see this if execution is not cancelled");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Execution was cancelled");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why'd you'd expect this to work.  You're not *doing* anything with your `CancellationTokenSource`. E.g. you aren't sending it to the method running the task.  It's essentially unused.  It can't just magically know what `Task` you want to cancel.

Comment: `async void` - This has "bad idea" written all over it.  It's going to be a lot easier for consuming code to cancel a task if you actually *return* a task.  Also, what does your `CancellationTokenSource` have to do with any of your tasks?

Comment: @David I had removed the return types in order to shrink the code the minimum lines to understand this problem. I'd just like to cancel the execution of DoSomethingAsync, and I thought this did not need to depend on what the method returned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it working, you actually need to use `CancellationToken` in the `SuperSlowProcess`:

```
public Task SuperSlowProcess(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        // you need to check cancellationToken periodically to check if cancellation has been requested
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // this will throw OperationCancelledException after CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is called
            Thread.Sleep(200); // to emulate super slow process
        }
    });

}
```

Of course, it depends on the implementation of `SuperSlowProcess`. If it's not possible to check `CancellationToken` periodically, you could check it only once - in the very end, something like that:

```
public async Task SuperSlowProcess2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await CallExternalApi();
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

and then

```
async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        await SuperSlowProcess(cts.Token);
        MessageBox.Show("You will only see this if execution is not cancelled");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) // Note that exception type is different
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Execution was cancelled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Periodically? But in my real use case this can't work... 
I am trying to cancel a method (the SuperSlowMethod) which gets content from an external source and I want it to stop as soon as the user closes the control in where the return data of the SuperSlowMethod is going to be printed, otherwise I will end up trying to write to an unavailable control.
If I do as you say, checking cancellation periodically, I risk that the method finishes between 1 period and another.. So.. is checking it periodically the only way to let the method now it has to stop executing?

Comment: @jj_ In this case, I see two options:
1. Pass `CancellationToken` down to the API you're using inside `SuperSlowMethod` if there are methods that accept `CancellationToken`
2. Inside `SuperSlowMethod` you can download required data and only then call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationrequested()`, so you'll check it only once in the end of async operation. That will guarantee that if cancellation has been requested, method will throw and won't attempt to render non-existing control

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd solution is what I was thinking, specifically because passing CancellationToken down to the API requires me to modify an actual external API I am loading as nuget package... as I said I am new to .NET so I am just guessing that in order to do that I'd need to get the sources of that nuget package, modify the source and recompile it?

Comment: You could find source code on GitHub if it's available and submit a PR. Or just stick to the second option and check cancellation token only once in the end. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: All said, I don't see how this is much different than just setting to *true* a simple bool "hasBeenCancelled" variable at object scope when clicking the cancel button, and then just checking that in the method at the end of it?

Comment: @jj_ in your particular case - yes, it might be as simple as checking setting/reading boolean field. However, in general `CancellationToken` gives you way more flexibility: quite often you can pass it to your own methods/external API/.NET libraries that without exposing access to some kind of shared mutable boolean `hasBeenCancelled` field. It also handles multi-threading and has some extra functions that might be handy, e.g. registering a callback that will be called when token is cancelled.